# Lens Distortion Effect with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I'm trying to model a lens distortion to apply to a vector image. I originally tried to use the Warp > Inflate effect, and I was able to get close in some scenarios to what I was looking for, but the problem is the inflate effect's scale is uniform throughout the x/y axis. The effect I'm looking for is for the effect to be on a logarithmic scale based on distance from the center.

I've got an example of what I'm looking for:

[image: Example]

The original image on the left, an approximation of what I'm looking for in the center, and what the inflate effect is doing on the right (note the consistent spacing in between each warped ring).

So I guess the main question is, does anyone know of an effect that can implement the effect I'm looking for? or am I stuck writing a custom plugin or something?

Answer (score 3):

Goto **Effect » Distort & Transform » Transform** apply values which shown in below image[image]

Comment: Ahh ... that's a pretty good way to achieve the specific effect. I guess I should have been more clear though, I wasn't necessarily looking to generate concentric circles, I was looking for an effect that is _similar_ to warp>inflate, but rather than a constant inflation factor (bulge is similar), matching the effect I describe in the question on an existing group of vector objects

Answer (score -1):

I know you're trying to do this to a vector image, but if you're willing to convert to bitmap then you can use Photoshops pucker tool to achieve this effect.

in PS filter > liquify > select pucker tool on the left

you can use the Freeze tool with a feather to prevent the center of the image from distorting too much, depending on what exactly you want.

It might be a bit messy, but you can convert back to Vector once you're done by using AIs image trace.

Hope this helps

Comment: the OP asks specifically about a vector image